# Passing more variables to matrix operator in pcg - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to call the function pcg (conjugate gradient) in Matlab using an matrix operator instead of a matrix.  The trouble is I want to pass to the matrix operator more than just the vector x. I also want to pass it another variable. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is really confusing. Could you show more explicitly what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by matrix operator?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to call the function [PCG](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pcg.html) with the first input being a [*function handle*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-38133.html) (what you are calling a *matrix operator*) to a function `afun` that accepts a vector input `X` and returns a matrix-vector product `A*X`. If you want to provide other variables to `afun` besides just `X`, you can [parameterize the function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/bsgprpq-5.html) using either [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) or [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html). Here's an anonymous function example:

```
A = [...];        %# Some matrix you want to use in your function
B = [...];        %# The other matrix to pass to PCG
afun = @(x) A*x;  %# Construct an anonymous function using the current value of A
X = pcg(afun,B);  %# Pass the anonymous function as the first argument
```